# How to compile FileMQ in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, zeromq, file-transfer, filemq

I want to implement FileMQ for file transfer from iOS to android in my iOS app. 
I tried the steps given [here](https://github.com/zeromq/filemq) but it causes errors at many steps. Also I need to know how should I use the downloaded library.

How should I compile FileMQ for iOS and use it?

Any information in this regard is appreciated!

Comment: No problem in down voting. But please let me know the reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded a C version of the library from the link mentioned in the question and compiled it on linux machine. I made some changes in the headers to make it iOS compatible as the headers were generated for linux. Now I am using the same copy in my iOS project.